# Compute $\int \int_{a \Omega} F_1 dxdy + F_2 dydz + F_3dzdx$ directly and by divergence theorem if $F_1 = 3y$, $F_2 = 18z$, $F_3 = -12$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Picture of question:

[image]

Question:

Let $\Omega$ be the triangular solid bounded by the $xy$-plane, the $xz$-plane, the $yz$-plane and the plane $2x + 3y + 6z = 12$. Compute $\int \int_{a \Omega} F_1 dxdy + F_2 dydz + F_3dzdx$ directly and by divergence theorem if $F_1 = 3y$, $F_2 = 18z$, $F_3 = -12$

My solution:

$\int \int_{a \Omega} F_1 dx dy = \int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{\frac{12-2x}{3}} 3 y dy dx = 48$

$\int \int_{a \Omega} F_2 dydz = \int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{4-y}{x}}18z dz dy = 48$

$\int \int_{a \Omega} F_3 dzdx = \int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{\frac{6-x}{2}} (-12)dzdx = -96$

total integral is $48 + 48 - 96 = 0$

by divergence theorem $\frac{d}{dx}(3y) + \frac{d}{dy}(18z) + \frac{d}{dz}(-12) = 0$

$$\int \int_{a \Omega} F_1 dx dy + \int \int_{a \Omega} F_2 dy dz + \int \int_{a \Omega} F_3 dz dx = \int \int \int_{\Omega} \triangledown F dV = 0$$

is this correct? I'm confused on the divergence theorem part